# notepad++ application related issue

Tags: windows-7

In notepad++ 7.3 we have enable few plugins which we can find out from plugin tab.
there is one more option inside the plugin tab is "show plugin manager". so my question is there any way we can disable that show plugin manager option so that we will not get any update related to plugin and also will not be able to install any extra plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your Notepad++ installation directory and remove/rename the `plugins` directory. That will get rid of the plugins menu altogether.

If you want to keep some of the Plugins I would expect it to be sufficient to rename/remove `PluginManager.dll` but that isn't working for me.

If it's just about updates go and check [Disable auto-update in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/132797/disable-auto-update-in-notepad).

Another option would be to edit the `PluginManager.ini` and either edit or remove the `PluginManagerPlugins.xml` file. It appears that by setting a high value for `LastCheck` Notepad++ won't be checking for new updates for the `PluginManagerPlugins.xml` file. If you clear the XML file it would display an empty list of available plugins. Alternatively you could probably supply a (false) proxy to let it fail the request. From my limited testing it seems to also work to remove the `PluginManagerPlugins.xml` and rename the `PluginManager.dll` in order for the Client to not download a new plugin list.

Comment: This is not about update. if we leave show plugin manager enabled, anyone will able  install the new plugins while click on install option and it will ask to insert the admin credentials MSG box.which normal user do not have.

Comment: Yes but you weren't specific on what your actual concern was either and as the other question points out there is an update option for the plugin manager as well. In addition you only mentioned you saw some plugins listed but not whenever you actually need them. As this answer points out, if you don't need any of those you can just rename/remove the folder to get rid of the menu entry altogether.

Comment: I want to hide or disable Show Plugin Manager from Notepad ++ application. Because If this option is enabled, Users can select the plugin that they want to install and click on install. as installation will need admin credentials, a pop keeps coming up every time when shortcut is launched. pop up can be disabled by removing plugin manger group.xml file. But we want to disable the "Show Plug in Manager" it self so that no body can even try to install any plugin at all.

Comment: Yes but do you want to pre-install any plugins? That is the question. if not, rename or remove the plugin directory and you will be done. I'm currently editing for yet another solution.

Comment: yes, correct we want some pre-install plugins. Other should not install plugin Other than the plugin we want to install,

Comment: Well I did include a solution for that as well. As for actually removing the shortcut it doesn't look like there is an option to do so. Indeed it would be kind of bad to not be able to see what is actually installed and deactivate them. You could head over to the [official forums](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community) and directly ask them. Maybe it could be done by writing a custom plugin (as strange as it sounds)?